# How to install SenchaCmd so that repo folder is created?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, extjs

I installed SenchaCmd  but there is no repo folder.
I installed it on Lubuntu 32bit and i am trying to use it with Extjs.  How should i install it for the repo folder to be created?

Comment: What do you mean by "repo" folder?